# How to change multiple column names in pandas according to a criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this -

```
Country|1980 YR1980|1981 YR1981|1982 YR 1982|...
     A | 1         |  -        |   2        |...
     B | -         |  1        |   2.5      |...
     c | -         |  0.433    |   4.7      |...
```

My aim is to remove from the column names: YR.... part. Actually I want to visualise the data and have years on my Y axis and countries on X axis and map the datapoints to the table.

Another idea is to plot a world map and make a slider below for years.

And my understanding is that for either case, we need the years to be integers.

My table has years in range - 1980 to 2013 (total 33)

I tried doing this:

```
list1= [i for i in range(33)]
new_Index=[str(i) for i in list1]
df = df.iloc[:,1:34].columns= new_Index
```

But got error:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6cf1843506e9> in <module>()
      1 list1= [i for i in range(33)]
      2 new_Index=[str(i) for i in list1]
----> 3 df = df.iloc[:,1:34].columns= new_Index

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: do you just want to remove the 'YR' and what follows part from the column names?

Comment: Yes, - like in 1980 YR1980, I want to retain only the starting 1980 and drop YR1980

Comment: okay please check below and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If need values of columns before first space use `str.split` with selecting by `str`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split().str[0]
```

If need set values use lists joined by `+`:

```
#exclude 2013
df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + list(range(1980, 2013))

#include 2013
#df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + list(range(1980, 2014))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
x = df.columns.tolist()
new_cols = [x.split()[-1].strip('YR') for x in x]
```